# Problems with ComboBox AutoComplete feature when Items are dynamically loaded

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

I am setting up a ComboBox to use the AutoComplete feature with AutoCompleteMode = Append and AutoCompleteSource = ListItems. When I load my form the Item list of the ComboBox is empty, and then I keep adding new values from the ComboBox.Text on a specified event (when a specific button is pressed).

Bottom line is that when the ComboBox's Items property is populated dynamically from an event, the AutoCompletion does not work as expected. My first entry into ComboBox.Items, always completes properly, but the later ones don't. If I click the arrow to dropdown the list, then all the Items so far entered autocomplete properly. If I Alt-Tab into another application and come back to the combobox, all the Items entered so far autocomplete properly.

It comes across to me that internally the combobox reloads its autocomplete list based on some event, but so far I have tried calling

```
ResumeLayout(true); 
Refresh(); 
Invalidate(true); 
Update(); 
DroppedDown = true; 
DroppedDown = false;
```

but to no avail

Can someone enlighten me on how to dynamically add entries in the ComboBox.Items list and still have auto-complete with ComboBox.AutoCompleteSource = ListItems work correctly.

btnExecute is the default button on the form which contains the combobox. So the below function is invoked on pressing enter on the combobox

```
private void btnExecute_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    cboCommand.SuspendLayout();
    cboCommand.Items.Add(cboCommand.Text);
    cboCommand.Text = "";
    // Make some call here, so combobox reloads its cache for autocompletion
}
```

relevant portion from the auto generated winforms code

```
this.cboCommand.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Append;
this.cboCommand.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.cboCommand.FormattingEnabled = true;
```

I am using .NET4 Client profile on Windows Vista. May be it plays a role here

Anyone?

Comment: Breaking this is difficult, you'd have to mess with the keystroke processing.  Post code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @justinb138: this is probably winfiorms, not asp.net.

Comment: Ah, k.  I see ComboBox and think WebForms, not WinForms.  Thanks!

Comment: This is WinForms and I just added some code to show what I am doing

Comment: Have you tried sorting the list after inserting new items?

Comment: I need to retain the order, so haven;t tried sorting

Comment: why not bind the combobox to a bindinglist, which will make sure it's updated on poulate?